# Kitsu API authentication returns invalid grant

Tags: api, curl

I'm trying to figure out on how to use the [Kitsu API](https://kitsu.docs.apiary.io/#reference/authentication) to make calls like updating entries etc. The thing is I'm already struggeling on the authentication. 
According to the documentation, the following would suffice for grant type password:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<myusername>&password=<mypassword>" https://kitsu.io/api/oauth/token
```

It results however in

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."}
```

The error makes is seem like this grant type doesn't exist (anymore), so I'm confused on how to proceed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I concluded that the API documentation contains some flaws. Instead of `<username>` it should be `<email>`, very confusing/annoying...